# Convert Image as File Type in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am modifying a method a in angular typescript where it was uploading an image using input element of type file and in the method event was getting passed. I have to modify a method as there is no input element now and I have a image file in my assets folder of angular project. So now I don't want to tamper the previously written code:

```
loadImages(event) {
const files = event.target.files;
if (this.CheckFileName(files[0].name) && this.CheckFileSize(files[0].size)) {
  let imageList = [];
  const fileList: Array<File> = Array.from(files);
  fileList.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    if (b.name > a.name)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  })
}
```

And now I want my file to be from "../../assets/images/0001.png".
How could I achieve the same by reading my image file from the given path and converting it to type File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fetch the image then convert it to the File object.

You will need to return an Observable instead of returning the value directly.

```
getImage() {
  return this.http
    .get("https://picsum.photos/id/34/200/300", {
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
   })
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        return new File([response], "myImage.png");
      })
    );
}
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbfcun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).